# GetX Controller - Wait for firebase RTDB stream to be populated

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-getx

I am new to GetX and want to get some concepts right. This is my process to get the groups that a current user is in using  `Firebase Realtime Database`:

1. Create an AuthController to get current user id (works perfectly)

   ````dart
   class AuthController extends GetxController {
     FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

     Rx<User?> firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);

     User? get user => firebaseUser.value;

     @override
     void onInit() {
       firebaseUser.bindStream(auth.authStateChanges());
       super.onInit();
     }
   } ```
   ````
2. Create a UserController to get ids of groups that the user has (working partially)

```dart
class FrediUserController extends GetxController {
  Rx<List<String>> groupIdList = Rx<List<String>>([]);

  List<String> get groupIds => groupIdList.value;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    User? user = Get.find<AuthController>().user;

    if (user != null) {
      String uid = user.uid;
      groupIdList.bindStream(DatabaseManager().userGroupIdsStream(uid));
      print(groupIds); //prints [] when it should be populated
    }
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

3. Create a GroupsController to get the groups from those ids (not working) --> Dependant on UserController to have been populated with the id's.

```dart
class FrediGroupController extends GetxController {
  Rx<List<FrediUserGroup>> groupList = Rx<List<FrediUserGroup>>([]);

  List<FrediUserGroup> get groups => groupList.value;

  void bindStream() {}

  @override
  void onInit() {
    final c = Get.find<FrediUserController>();
    List<String> groupIds = c.groupIds;
    print(groupIds); //prints [], when it should have ids
    groupList.bindStream(DatabaseManager().groupsStream(groupIds)); //won't load anything without id's

    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

### Observations

- Get.put is called sequentially in the main.dart file:

```
  Get.put(AuthController());
  Get.put(FrediUserController());
  Get.put(FrediGroupController());
```

- Inside my HomePage() Stateful Widget, if I call the `UserController`, the data loads correctly:

```dart
    GetX<FrediUserController>(
                  builder: (controller) {
                    List<String> groups = controller.groupIds;
                     print(groups); //PRINTS the list of correct ids. THE DATA LOADS.
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: groups.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text('${groups[index]}', 
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                                                        },),); },),
```

### QUESTION

It is as if the stream takes some time to populate, but the `UserController` doesn't wait for it and initializes the controller as empty at first, but after some time it populates (not in time to pass the data to the `GroupController`.

How can I fix this? I have tried async but not with much luck.

Behaviour I would Like:

- Streams may/may not be ready, so it can initialize as empty or not.
- HOWEVER, if the stream arrives, everything should be updted, including the initialization of controllers that depend on `UserController` like `GroupController`.
- Consequently, the UI is rebuilt with new values.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that you can add:

1. Future Builder to show some loading screen while it fetch data from RTDB
2. ever function

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
late Rx<User?> firebaseuser;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    firebaseuser = Rx<User?>(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    firebaseuser.bindStream(FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges());
    ever(firebaseuser, _setInitialScreen);
  }

  _setInitialScreen(User? user) {

    if (user != null) {
      //User Logged IN
      
    } else {
      //User Logged out
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am testing, and , my ever function is  being called when using a String observable but not when using a custom class observable. Are there any differences?

Comment: please check related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667479/getx-observable-works-with-list-but-not-custom-class

Answer (score 1):

You only take the user once, in the method onInit. You are not getting user changes. To get every change you would have to use "ever" function. For example, "firebaseUser.value" is like a photography of the firebaseUser observable in the moment.

If I can make a sugestion, don't mistake controllers with providers. Think Firebase as a provider and the controller as a mid point between the UI and the provider. You can listen to Firebase Streams at the controller to update UI and make calls from the UI change parameters in your Firebase provider. Separate your concerns into two distinct classes and you'll, potentially, have a better design.

Use of "ever" function example:

```
ever(firebaseUser, (user) {
   // do something 
});
```

"Ever" assigned function runs whenever the observable emits a new value

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide an example of how to use an 'ever' function?

Comment: I've added an example. You can call it on onInit

Comment: please check related quesion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667479/getx-observable-works-with-list-but-not-custom-class